# How to start a session after user has signed up

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm making a login system system, and after the user has signed up and the information has been stored in the database, i want to automatically login the user. As of now the user just gets an AJAX message, but no session is started

This is my attempt so far, but

*User information is stored through sql above this code*

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["email"]=$row["email"];
header("Location: http://domain.dk/profile.php");

$conn=null; //disconnect to server
?>
```

It seems that the session starts, but the code in my if/else statement on the profile page, is only shown, if the user gets there from the login page, and not the signup page

Comment: `var_dump($row)` `var_dump($_SESSION)`

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: You need to make sure that you have at the top of each script something like this for example: `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}` You can put it in a separate file  and include it once (or if you have a shared file that you always include)

Comment: Check whether session is there or not. Use: print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: I can see in the chrome dev tool that the session is set, and i set the session in the same way from the login page and the register page, but the content isnt shown if i come from the register page